# Select from literal values not in table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some values in Excel, I copy the values and it look like this:

1
2
3
4

I want to write a query that select from above data that is not present in a table. Somethink like:

```
SELECT * FROM [1, 2, 3, 4] as foo where foo IS NOT ( SELECT id from table )
```

Supposing id column have 1,2,4 the query answer will be 3.

Preferably a query that can work in postgres and sql server

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a `left join` or something similar for this.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(foo) 
WHERE foo NOT IN ( SELECT id from table );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from
    (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) v (id)
    left join
    t using (id)
where t.id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
Select * from unnest(array[1,2,3,4]) as id
```